# Plotting a graph of iterations in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, graph

I've written the following piece of code using the Euler method to plot a graph of velocity against time for a free-falling object, which eventually reaches terminal velocity:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = -9.81
Cd = 0.47
p0 = 1.2
A = 0.0034
k = (Cd*p0*A)/2
m = 0.058


def euler(vyn, yn): #takes the starting velocity and height as arguments
    i = 0
    while i < 10000:
        dt = 0.01
        i += 1
        vyn = vyn - dt * (g + ((k/m) * abs(vyn) * vyn))
        yn = yn - dt * vyn
        print(vyn, yn)

        if yn < 0: #stops iterations when ball hits ground
            break
    return vyn 

NumPoints = 2000
xmin = 0
xmax = 1000
dx = (xmax - xmin) / (NumPoints - 1)
xvals = [0.0] * NumPoints
yvals = np.zeros(NumPoints)
for i in range(NumPoints):
    xvals[i] = xmin + i * dx
    yvals[i] = euler(0,1000)
    plt.plot(xvals,yvals)
plt.show()
```

I put the print statement in the while loop by the way so that it prints the velocity and height of object from the ground each iteration, and the break is so that it breaks out of the loop by the time the ball hits the ground. However, when I add the graphing code at the bottom, the iterations loop back round for some reason, without breaking. A graph is also not printed.

Removing the print statement does produce a graph, however it is just a horizontal line.

How could I modify the code to produce a graph of velocity against time, and also height against time? Do I need to embed the graph code within the while loop?

Thanks

Comment: 1) The indentation of `plt.plot(xvals,yvals)` is wrong. You only want to plot the pairs x,y at the end. 2) Your y values always calculate euler(0,1000), they don't differ for different x values. Ergo you get a line, because all y values are the same.

Comment: Please fix the indentation, especially at the end.  The posted code won't run due to the illegal indentation of `plt.plot`.  Also, that line should *not* be inside the loop: you need to compute all the values (`NumPoints` iterations) and then plot *once*.

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  What happens if you hard-code your x-y values and try to plot?  You have several structural variables here; you should isolate the one(s) that *actually* cause trouble.